# Best way to do enable drag and drop for nested resources for ActiveAdmin in Show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am trying to implement a drag and drop to reorder from the show page in active admin. I have seen a lot of tutorial for the index page but nothing for the show page. What is the best way to do it?

[image: adminpanel]

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) has a drag and drop functionality that you can customize to run a callback function to send an AJAX request that updates the ordering of your form.